# Same query, same DB, different execution plans & dramatically different times to execute

Tags: sql-server

I'm confronted with a problem I cannot get my mind around. We're running SQL Server 2012. I have run into a pair of essentially identical queries which yield different execution plans and dramatically different times to execute (1 sec vs 40+ sec)... and they even return the exact same records. The only difference between them is the category the records are queried by.

This query runs in 1 second:

```
SELECT P.idProduct, P.sku, P.description, P.price, P.listhidden, P.listprice, P.serviceSpec, P.bToBPrice, P.smallImageUrl,P.noprices,P.stock, P.noStock,P.pcprod_HideBTOPrice,P.pcProd_BackOrder,P.FormQuantity,P.pcProd_BTODefaultPrice,cast(P.sDesc as varchar(8000)) sDesc, 0, 0, P.pcprod_OrdInHome, P.sales, P.pcprod_EnteredOn, P.hotdeal, P.pcProd_SkipDetailsPage 
FROM products P INNER JOIN categories_products CP ON P.idProduct = CP.idProduct 
WHERE CP.idCategory=494 AND active=-1 AND configOnly=0 and removed=0 AND formQuantity=0   
AND ((SELECT TOP 1 SP.stock FROM products SP WHERE SP.pcprod_ParentPrd = P.idProduct AND SP.description LIKE N'%(9-12 Months)' AND SP.removed=0) > 0) 
ORDER BY P.description Asc
```

The second runs 40 seconds or more, but the ONLY difference is the `idCategory` queried:

```
SELECT P.idProduct, P.sku, P.description, P.price, P.listhidden, P.listprice, P.serviceSpec, P.bToBPrice, P.smallImageUrl,P.noprices,P.stock, P.noStock,P.pcprod_HideBTOPrice,P.pcProd_BackOrder,P.FormQuantity,P.pcProd_BTODefaultPrice,cast(P.sDesc as varchar(8000)) sDesc, 0, 0, P.pcprod_OrdInHome, P.sales, P.pcprod_EnteredOn, P.hotdeal, P.pcProd_SkipDetailsPage 
FROM products P INNER JOIN categories_products CP ON P.idProduct = CP.idProduct 
WHERE CP.idCategory=628 AND active=-1 AND configOnly=0 and removed=0 AND formQuantity=0   
AND ((SELECT TOP 1 SP.stock FROM products SP WHERE SP.pcprod_ParentPrd = P.idProduct AND SP.description LIKE N'%(9-12 Months)' AND SP.removed=0) > 0) 
ORDER BY P.description Asc
```

They even return the exact same records in the exact same order.

Execution plan for the 1st query:[image]

Execution plan for the 2nd query:
[image]

[EDIT] The plans here are the *actual*, not the *estimated*, execution plans.

The `categories_products` table is a simple lookup table with only the two fields `idCategory` and `idProduct`. Even the records returned are exactly the same (it just happens to be that for `SP.description LIKE N'%(9-12 Months)'`, the same products are assigned to these 2 categories). The only other difference between the two is that `CP.idCategory` 628 was just created this morning (but i don't see what difference that could make).
[EDIT: but that's exactly what did make the difference]

How can this be? How can simply changing the `CP.idCategory` queried here yield a different execution plan, and even more importantly: how is it that one takes some 40 times as long to execute?

Ultimately, I'm at a loss to figure out how to improve the dreadful performance of the 2nd query given that there's no essential difference between the two that I can understand.

Comment: So if you hover over the _products_ table scan in both cases, what is it searching on? If you run this and include the _actual_ plan, do you see any differences in actual and estimated row counts?

Comment: It could also be that the second query has a bad cached plan and the first one doesn't.

Comment: I've occasionally seen similar behaviour when significant amounts of rows have been added or modified. Usually it has helped me to manually refresh the statistics on the involved tables. But the execution plan (for the slow query) spells out that there is an index missing. Try to create it and see what happens...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, the execution plans I shared are the _actual_ execution plans.

For the 1st query, the actual & estimated rows are the same: 169689. For the 2nd, estimated rows is 1 & actual is 66.

When you say run "this", I'm not sure what "this" is.

RE: "bad cached plan", how might one investigate that and what could be done about that?

Comment: Sorry by "run this" I meant run it and get the actual plan - which is what you've already done. This link has a query that lists all queries in the cache: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/11/t-sql-queries/multiple-plans-identical-query although by now I expect it's pretty full so it mightn't tell you much. To force a new plan you can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. If this fixes it you know it's most likely a bad plan in the cache http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70809/

Comment: Thanks @user1429080... a significant number of rows were indeed added  just before this problem surfaced (namely to the `categories_products` lookup table assigning everything from the 1st query to the category in the 2nd query). Updating Statistics through an SSMS maintenance plan cleared up the immediate issue.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid & Bogdan Sahlean for your recommendations. I am looking into them as well for how they might also help mitigate against a surprise like this catching us off guard again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is `description` column. The length of `description` of idCategory[628] longer than idCategory[494]. Because you are using `SP.description LIKE N'%(9-12 Months)'`. Length of `description` is too long then you get slowly.

Also you are using `ORDER BY P.description Asc`.

Comment: Thanks @Tien Nguyen, but the `description` column belongs to the `products` table, and the resulting record set is exactly the same for both queries in this case. So the lengths of all `description`'s here are the same.

Comment: I see. How many products are in idCategory[628] and idCategory[494]? And each product have to use **description LIKE**. So it will be slowly.